# Extract data from truth table pandas

Tags: python, pandas, truthtable

I'm given a truth table and am looking to create a table of lists using it.  I see lots of tips about how to create a truth table but not much about how to go back.  Of course I could do this with a few loops but I figure there's probably a slick pandas way to do this that would be much more satisfying.  Consider the dataframe below, detailing the vehicles that a person owns:

```
+-------+------------+-----+----------+
| Name  | motorcycle | car | unicycle |
+-------+------------+-----+----------+
| Sarah |          1 |   0 |        1 |
| Mike  |          0 |   1 |          |
| Doug  |          1 |   1 |        0 |
+-------+------------+-----+----------+
```

I would like to reshape it into this:

```
+-------+------------------------+
| Name  |        vehicle         |
+-------+------------------------+
| Sarah | [motorcycle, unicycle] |
| Mike  | [car]                  |
| Doug  | [motorcycle, car]      |
+-------+------------------------+
```

Is there a slick pandas way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you provide some code for building your dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your trying to reverse a pd.get_dummies, melt or pivot table might owrk

Here the is the melt approach

`df.melt(id_vars='Name', var_name='vehicle').query('value == 1').groupby('Name').agg({'vehicle': list})`

```
                      vehicle
Name                         
Doug        [motorcycle, car]
Mike                    [car]
Sarah  [motorcycle, unicycle]
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, we can use `melt`, `loc` and `groupby` with `agg(list)` note this will only work in pandas 0.24+

```
s = df.melt(id_vars='Name',var_name='vehicle')
new_df = s.loc[s['value'] == 1].groupby('Name')['vehicle'].agg(list).to_frame()
```

---

```
print(new_df)

                   vehicle
Name                      
 Doug    [motorcycle, car]
 Mike                [car]
 Sarah        [motorcycle]
```